# bind udp problem

Tags: windows-server-2008, bind, udp

I am using bind 9.6.1 and about 2 days ago I realized that there is a bug at bind for windows platform.

when server gets 
"UDP client handler shutting down due to fatal receive error: host unreachable"
error. it stays alive but no response for after dns queries. then I need to restart it manually to make it responsive(I put a task for this issue from windows). I cant use microsoft windows dns server because I am using windows 2008 server web edition which does not include that.

so my question is what are the other solutions you use for dns server in windows ?

Comment: is this an authoritative server or recursive only?

Comment: I dunno real difference. I just bought dedicated server and installed bind9 on it. and configure the domains and its working normally fine. but sometime it stops because of that udp stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I have this EXACT same issue. It seems to be a known bug.

http://forum.parallels.com/pda/index.php/t-85129.html
https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/bind-users/2009-January/074803.html

Not that I can find a fix anywhere. Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found patched 9.5.x version from securityfocus and tried that one too. but it did not solved the udp problem. so at the end I installed vmware and move all dns issues to solid rock debian installation. now there is no complain about dns and timeouts.